# How can I get more information about Work Profile of my phone

Tags: work-profiles

Google describes Work profile as something that the organization manages, but my question is how can I make sure that my organization (or whoever else) does NOT have access/control to the work profile on my phone?
I have my personal Pixel phone, and as far as I remember the only work-related stuff on it is a Google account (our company uses Google Apps) and Google Authenticator app - both added by myself. I don't think I ever had a work profile until now when I installed a Shelter app. So I assume that in my case the Work profile is not actually controlled/accessed by anyone except myself. Is there any way to confirm this?